# I used a != b != c: and it does not give me the correct results for b != a == c

Tags: python, if-statement

This is a question from codingbat Logic-2 https://codingbat.com/prob/p143951

Given 3 int values, a b c, return their sum. However, if one of the values is the same as another of the values, it does not count towards the sum.

```
lone_sum(1, 2, 3) → 6
lone_sum(3, 2, 3) → 2
lone_sum(3, 3, 3) → 0



def lone_sum(a, b, c):
  if a != b != c:
    return a+b+c

  if a == b !=c:
    return c

  if a != b == c:
    return a

  if b != a == c:
    return b

  if a == b == c:
    return 0

  if a != b != c:
    return a+b+c
```

I expect `one_sum(3, 2, 3) → 2` but I got 8
so it must have done 3+2+3 but why?

Same for `lone_sum(2, 9, 2) → 9` but I got 13
so 2+9+2 again

Comment: because `3 != 2` and `2 != 3` chained comparisons. just perform 3 tests. `a !=b and b != c and a != c`

Comment: Because your first case doesn't compare a with c

Comment: On an unrelated note, this is not the best way to approach this problem. What would you do if there were 100 arguments instead of 3? Consider making a list out of arguments and try to think of a more generic algorithm as a learning experiment.